# Update UI rendering in React Natives 'focus' Event Listener

Tags: ios, reactjs, swift, react-native

I am navigating from different class objects (screens) within my React Native App. Once I navigate to a given screen, I want to execute different functions including Activity Indicators to show that the function is still running.

Therefore is set up a `focus` Event Listener which is called every time I navigate back to my screen. My current problem is that my Activity Indicators are not updated within the `focus` Event but directly after, which is not my wanted behavior as I have to wait for my functions to end without any visual indicator.

````
class Homescreen extends Component {
   constructor(props){
     super(props};
     this.state = {
       showIndicator: false;
     }
   }
   componentDidMount(){
     this.props.navigation.addListener('focus', this._onFocus);
   }
   componentWillUnmount(){
     this.props.navigation.removeListener('focus', this._onFocus);
   }
   _onFocus = async () => {
     this.setState({showIndicator: true});
     asyncFunc();
   };
   async asyncFunc(){
     //calling a function from swift which calls a C function inside DispatchQeue.main.async
     //inside my C function I successfully set my ActivityIndicator to false with an Event which calls
     //this.setState({showIndicator: false});
   }
  render(){
    console.log(this.state.showIndicator); // correct value is printed while I wait inside the ```focus``` Event to finish, but the UI is not updated.
    return(
       {this.state.showIndicator && <ActivityIndicator/>}
    )
  }
}
````

I receive the correct current status of `showIndicator`but before the `focus` Event is not finished, my render does not redraw.
To me it seems like the UI won't update until I am out of my `focus` Event. How can I reach my goal of displaying the `ActivityIndicator` before the `focus` Event or how do I call my function right after the `focus` Event?

I can achieve my wanted behavior by using the `blur`event and setting my `ActivityIndicator` visible while moving to another screen and after moving back I wait until my function is finished and remove the `ActivityIndicator` but this seems like a bad workaround and also I can see the `ActivityIndicator` when moving which might be confusing.

Answer (score 0):

You should replace curly braces around this statement {this.state.showIndicator && } and check.

If it doesn't work accordingly then let me know.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. That's not the problem, I also switched to the display: this.state.showIndicator property with 'flex' and 'none' and neither are shown either

Comment: Did you check it with  "didFocus" ?

Comment: I used ```ComponentDidUpdate()``` to make it work.